# FreeBSD : Definition of BUS_TEARDOWN_INTR not found

Tags: c, freebsd

In source code of FreeBSD, a method bus_teardown_intr in sys/kern/subr_bus.c is calling "BUS_TEARDOWN_INTR". What does BUS_TEARDOWN_INTR do? I am unable to find the definition of it.

I am attaching part of the code for reference

```
int
bus_teardown_intr(device_t dev, device_t child, struct resource *irq,
    void *cookie)
{

    if (dev->parent)
        return (EINVAL);
    return (BUS_TEARDOWN_INTR(dev->parent, child, irq, cookie));
}
```

Here is the link to the code " fxr.watson.org/fxr/source/kern/subr_bus.c ", 
line number 4177 corresponds to the above code.

Comment: Huh? Are those asterisks really there in the code? Adding characters which are very syntactically interesting isn't a good idea.

Comment: no those are'nt part of the code, I marked BUS_TEARDOWN_INTR as bold it got represented with **.

Comment: Which FreeBSD version or branch?

Answer (score 3):

It is a generated function by `sys/tools/makeobjops.awk`. Look at `sys/kern/bus_if.m` for the source.

You can see the generated code in GENERIC/bus_if.h in your object directory after a kernel build. (or substitute your kernel name for GENERIC if you've changed it.)

The function also has a man page. type:

```
man 9 BUS_TEARDOWN_INTR
```

To read the documentation.